# Is it possible to show a clean error if the user does not have the required version of .NET installed?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, error-handling

I have done and can't find any answer but is it possible to show a clean error if the user does not have the required version of .NET installed instead of the standard unadulterated exception window?

Comment: Workaround: Create an installer for your app and have the installer if the required .NET framework is installed. Even better would be to make .NET a prerequisite in the installer so it gets installed automatically and you don't have to bother the user at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always can check if .NET installed.  Here's the article that describes how to do that.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18574/Is-NET-Framework-installed-on-this-machine

Of course you'll need to do that in un-managed code.

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't - your app has no chance to run because there is no .Net framework available to run it, so there is no way to show anything other than the normal Windows error dialog.

One workaround is to create a bootstrapper (startup executable) in .Net 2.0 - this was shipped in a service pack for Windows XP and has been included in every operating system since. This bootstrapper can then check for the required .Net framework install, and show a nice error message if it doesn't exist - you could even install it for the user (we have a custom installer that operates in exactly this way, and we ship the .Net framework redistributables as part of the package so we can install them and initiate the required reboot if the user wants to).

Comment: A variation could be that your application has a very small unmanaged .exe that only loads your .net code when the required version is found. Although probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Why not build a proper installer? You can't guarantee that the user will have .Net 2. The .Net framework is optional and the [users might have removed it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/04/10149346.aspx).

Comment: @MarkJ I agree, however I'm simply answering the question within the parameters the OP has stated. As for our installer that I talk of - it sets up an enterprise type solution and we stipulate to the client that they must have at least .Net 2.0 installed - we are in a position to be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Useful Workaround: Create an installer application that checks for the .NET run-time. Then, if not found download and install the .NET Framework for the end-user.

Possible solutions for this can be created with Inno Setup. See: [Downloading and Installing .NET 4.0 with Inno Setup](http://www.stintercorp.com/articles/developer/innosetup_dotnetinstaller.aspx) as a starting point.